# How to search for Ads using the AdMob API

Tags: admob, app-inventor

AdMob in App Inventor, is it possible?

Comment: @Cody: Why is it not showing the ad? I am not using the SDK. I am using App Inventor.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There's [a request to add support for ads](http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=1098), which currently has 49 votes.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python to show admob in a webpage using AdMob's php based API. Then show that webpage in the WebViewer component.